# Is it dangerous to let user embed images from their own urls?

Tags: html, image, security

Would it compromise the security of a website if users were allowed to create img tags with whatever src attribute they wanted?

What kind of damage would be possible?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about IT Security. Should be migrated.

Comment: `<img src="http://example.com/myNastyScript.php">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allowing arbitrary `src` values on an `<img>` element would allow [Cross-Site Scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) and thus the execution of arbitrary JavaScript code on your page:

```
<img src="javascript:…">
```

It could also be used to forge arbitrary GET requests, similar to [Cross-Site Request Forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) but with a referrer originating from your site.

Answer (score 0):

can also be exploited to track your website visitors by using a web bug http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_bug